# How can I convert this messy jQuery to be less bloated and responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm using jQuery cycle2 and the carousel plugin to display some events on my site. It all works great but I want the visible option to change from 5 to 3 on tablets (between 768px and 1030px) and then down to 1 on phones (less than 768px). All of the other options can remain the same. This code is hacked together and messy, so I'm looking for a better way to do it. Also, currently it only works on refresh. That's fine, but it would be nice if it reloaded and worked in real-time when you resize. Here's my current code:

```
// Events
var ww = document.body.clientWidth;
$(document).ready(function() {
    adjustEvents();
})
$(window).bind('resize orientationchange', function() {
    ww = document.body.clientWidth;
    adjustEvents();
});

var adjustEvents = function() {
    if (ww > 1030) {
        $('.cycle').cycle({
            fx:'carousel',
            swipe:true,
            timeout:5000,
            slides:'> article',
            carouselVisible:5,
            carouselFluid:true,
            autoHeight:'calc',
            prev:'#prev',
            next:'#next'
        });
    } 
    else if (ww >= 768) {
        $('.cycle').cycle({
            fx:'carousel',
            swipe:true,
            timeout:5000,
            slides:'> article',
            carouselVisible:3,
            carouselFluid:true,
            autoHeight:'calc',
            prev:'#prev',
            next:'#next'
        });
    }
    else if (ww < 768) {
        $('.cycle').cycle({
            fx:'carousel',
            swipe:true,
            timeout:5000,
            slides:'> article',
            carouselVisible:1,
            carouselFluid:true,
            autoHeight:'calc',
            prev:'#prev',
            next:'#next'
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Move the `bind` call inside your `.ready()` handler.

Comment: @Mathletics - why? That would do absolutely nothing.

Comment: @Adam ha, you're right! I'm so used to keeping everything inside a `ready` handler I'd forgotten _why_. Chalk it up to lack of sleep?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(adjustEvents);
$(window).on('resize orientationchange', adjustEvents);

function adjustEvents() {
    var ww  = document.body.clientWidth,
        vis = ww > 1030 ? 5 : (ww >= 768 ? 3 : 1);
    $('.cycle').cycle({
        fx              : 'carousel',
        swipe           : true,
        timeout         : 5000,
        slides          : '> article',
        carouselVisible : vis,
        carouselFluid   : true,
        autoHeight      : 'calc',
        prev            : '#prev',
        next            : '#next'
    });
}
```

Comment: Nice - tidier than mine.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. Any way it can re-initialize on actual resize instead of reload?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a "trimmed" version of the code...

```
// Events
var ww = document.body.clientWidth;
$(document).ready(function() {
    adjustEvents();
})
$(window).bind('resize orientationchange', function() {
    ww = document.body.clientWidth;
    adjustEvents();
});

var adjustEvents = function() {
    var options = {
        fx:'carousel',
        swipe:true,
        timeout:5000,
        slides:'> article',
        carouselFluid:true,
        autoHeight:'calc',
        prev:'#prev',
        next:'#next'
    }

    if (ww > 1030) {
        options.carouselVisible = 5;
    } 
    else if (ww >= 768) {
        options.carouselVisible = 3;
    }
    else if (ww < 768) {
        options.carouselVisible = 1;
    }
    $('.cycle').cycle(options);
}
```

All I really did was create a variable to store the cycle options in, and only change the 1 property that was relevant to each width.